# How to plot a function depending on a condition?

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting several functions at once:

```
rotationAngle = 0;
x01 = 100;
y01 = 200;

Plot[
  {
    Tan[rotationAngle] x - Tan[rotationAngle] x01 + y01,
    Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2] x - Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2] x01 + y01
  },
  {x, -100, 100}
];
```

The problem is, that when `rotationAngle` has a value, which implicates the `Tan[Pi/2]` expression, I get a warning `Indeterminate expression 200+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered` and nothing is plotted.

I understand that the problem is with the expression `Tan[Pi/2]` which is undefined, so is there a way to circumvent this?

I tried to use `ConditionalExpression`:

```
Plot[
  {
    ConditionalExpression[
      Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2] x - Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2] x01 + y01,
      rotationAngle != 0
    ]
  },
  {x, -100, 100}
];
```

but that hasn't helped, the warning is still there.

The `If` statement cannot be inserted inside the `Plot` one, I tried this either.

So the question is: **Is there a way to plot a function only when a condition is true, and otherwise omit it, while plotting every other function?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want an empty plot or no plot?

Comment: @JohnDoty, I want no graph for exactly that function, because I'm plotting other functions in the same `Plot` call, and they must be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If[rotationAngle != 0,
 Plot[Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2]*x - Tan[rotationAngle + Pi/2]*x01 + 
   y01, {x, -100, 100}]
 ]
```

**Edit:**

To handle problems with single functions in multifunction plots, you could instead do something like this:

```
f = Function[{theta, offset},
  If[OddQ[(theta + offset)*2/Pi],
   Nothing,
   Function[x, Tan[theta + offset]*x - Tan[theta + offset]*x01 + y01]
   ]]

Plot[Evaluate@{f[rotationAngle, 0][x], 
   f[rotationAngle, Pi/2][x]}, {x, -100, 100}]
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I would like to avoid it, because it will induce a considerable amount of copy/paste code

Comment: Why copy/paste?

Comment: @JohnDoty because, I'm plotting several functions in one `Plot` call. So I would need to write `If … Plot [func1, func2_variant1], Plot[func1, func2_var2]` and so on

Comment: where `func1` will be an exact copy of another `func1` etc.

Comment: actually, I decided to comment out the erroneous functions by hand with `(* *)`, but the answer, that there is no simpler way is by itself pretty satisfactory

Comment: yes, I noticed, thank you. It would just be too complicated. I'm using Mathematica as a quick way to check another program, which I'm working on.  Now the Mathematica script has already become too complicated, so that I will spend more time debugging it, than the other program

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `Mathematica` is fundamentally an expression rewriting system. Get it to rewrite your code, don't cut and paste.

First, define a function that makes one plot, and yields `Nothing` if the plot cannot be made:

```
pl[angle_, x01_, y01_] := 
 Plot[Tan[angle] x - Tan[angle] x01 + y01, {x, -100, 100}] /; 
  Mod[angle, Pi] != Pi/2
pl[angle_, x01_, y01_] := Nothing
```

Then, construct a list of plots and `Show` them together. `Nothing` is automagically removed:

```
Show[Table[pl[a, 100, 200], {a, 0, Pi/2, Pi/2}]]
```